# How to customize requests and response rotate log

Tags: node.js

I'm using "winston-daily-rotate-file" to rotate logs and it is so good
but now my log files print too much data (all Https requests and all HTTP responses for all users per day)

any way to customize the requested URLs and response?
what I mean is that can I make this logger file prints specific requests data as demand

For Example:

```
29/04/2020 09:22:04.050 info: [GET] [/api/news/getNews]
29/04/2020 09:22:04.337 info: [GET] [/api/dashboard/vt]
29/04/2020 09:22:04.342 info: [401] [Unauthorized]
29/04/2020 09:22:04.664 info: [200] [OK]
29/04/2020 09:22:05.196 info: [GET] [/api/account/getVersion]
29/04/2020 09:22:05.199 info: [200] [OK]
```

I have these logs and i want the print the `/api/news/getNews` request with its response  and `/api/account/getVersion` as well

Comment: can you share more details it is very specific !!!

Comment: Thank you for that but can you show the Log you want to be specifically log out for the user !! i hope you understand what i am trying to say :)

Comment: @SaadSohail what about now? :))